# MDB bean pool vs Spring JMS concurrent consumers

Tags: spring, thread-safety, ejb-3.0, messaging, spring-jms

I am from EJB background working on MDBs for asychronus message processing. Recently I am moved to a project where Spring messaging is used . Being new to Spring JMS listeners , I am kind of confused when it comes to comparing the concurrency semantics with MDBs.

MDB - As I understand , we dont need to worry about thread safety , it maintains a pool of MDB beans (Pool size is something we can configure) . Whenever a new message comes to destination (queue) . EJB Container picks an instance from the pool and process the message .

Spring - I am not sure if I understand it completely . We define a listener class inside a container . I don't know if it will process every in-coming message with a new instance of listener-class or it will create a new thread ( like we have in servlets ) ? Another thing I  am confused with is configurable parameter concurrentConsumers , is it similar to what we have pool of beans in EJB container ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring semantics are applied, so in the typical case your listener bean is a singleton and you have to guarantee thread safety yourself. Of course this is trivial: if you had this

```
public class MDB implements MessageListener {
    public void onMessage(Message inMessage) {
        ...blablabla...
    }
}
```

Now you could have basically:

```
public class SpringMessageListener implements MessageListener {
    public void onMessage(Message inMessage) {
        MDB mdb = new MDB(...parameters MDB might need...);
        mdb.onMessage(inMessage);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank for the swift response  . As you said , its a singleton, what about concurrentconsumers setting , lets say if I say it to 5 . will it not create five instances of listener  ? Isn't it same to what we have as a pool size in MDB ?

Comment: No. Assuming your are using `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`  (or DMLC for friends) and a singleton listener, it will create 5 *listener container tasks* that will try to consume messages using *the same listener*. That is why I wrote how you can easily "convert" from `MDB`s to Spring listeners. As a last observation, note that "listener container tasks" *does not necessarily* mean "concurrent threads".

Comment: Thanks gpeche..I see your point, so in this way its different from what we have in EJB container...we have to ensure the thread safety on our own in case of spring messaging........though , I did not get your last point  "listener container tasks " difference from threads ....also this concurrent container tasks (or threads) will ensure that , now my listener can process 5 message parallel y. Am I correct ?

Comment: Spring will schedule those *listener container tasks* through some mechanism (usually some thread pool). If that thread pool is configured with, say, 3 threads, then you will have *effectively* 3 concurrent consumers maximum, while the other two remain enqueued.

Comment: As a general rule, in the Java EE world you have the container creating beans and / or enqueuing requests to ensure everything is thread safe so the developer does not have to worry about that. In contrast, when you use Spring most things are usually singletons, so you have to care about thread safety.

Comment: So my setting of concurrent Consumers is just a hint to Sprint container.  Controlling the number of threads in the thread pool is done by Spring container , or I can configure them as well?

Comment: `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` provides a `setTaskExecutor(Executor taskExecutor)` method through which you can inject whatever `Executor`implementation you want.